# error occured like myclass() takes no arguments

Tags: python

```
class MyClass(object):
    def _init_(self,a,b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
    def mp(self):
        print("hello")
F=MyClass(10,20)
F.mp()
```

## error occured with my constructor

Comment: class MyClass(object):
        def _init_(self,a,b):
            self.a=a
            self.b=b
        def dsply(self):
            print("hello")
    F=MyClass(10,20)
    F.mp()

Comment: The methods name should be `__init__` (with double underscores). BTW, `dsply` is an ugly name. The code won't run faster if you use shorter names. Call it `display` because that's what it does.

Comment: you defined your `init` method wrong, it's two underscores before and after that is the issue

Comment: you have few syntax mistakes (__init__ should be with double underscores) and  'MyClass' object has no attribute 'mp'

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to display "hello" you should call the dsply method by replacing {`F.mp`} with {`F.dsply`}

Comment: @Deva: Then please read the comments to your question and fix that typo.

Comment: I made all changes what ever u guys said but still error occured like (MyClass takes no arguments)

Comment: That's not possible. Please edit your question and copy and paste your current code. Does your method `__init__` really have two leading and trailing underscores?